# Big query dry run - significantly inconsistent estimate

Tags: google-bigquery

BigQuery bytes processed estimates seem to be different by a mile when querying the same data set at different points of time.

I have table A at t0 point of time. I ran the BigQuery dry run on that table and received an estimate of ~35Tb. I dry-run queried the table again with the same query, around a week (t1) later and received an estimate of ~7Gb. I checked in the information schema. No data was removed from the table between t0 and t1.

The only way I was able to replicate it was by using `SYSTEM_TIME` feature of BigQuery:

```
SELECT * 
      FROM placesTable
      FOR SYSTEM_TIME AS OF TIMESTAMP('2023-10-10T17:25:00')
     WHERE (date_time BETWEEN "2023-04-08 00:00:00+00:00" AND "2023-05-08 00:00:00+00:00") 
     AND lon >= 122.13 AND lon <= 122.138 AND lat >=  15.44 AND lat <= 16.447
```

and

```
SELECT * 
      FROM placesTable
      WHERE (date_time BETWEEN "2023-04-08 00:00:00+00:00" AND "2023-05-08 00:00:00+00:00") 
      AND lon >= 122.13 AND lon <= 122.138 AND lat >=  15.44 AND lat <= 16.447
```

Second query was run at 2023-10-19T17:26:00 and between both runs no data was added nor removed.

Still BigQuery estimated first query to process ~35Tb and second query to process ~7Gb. I expected these two queries to have the same estimates.

Do you have any idea what is happening here?

Comment: BigQuery is calculating the estimations very poorly especially when there table has a clustering. Do you have by any chance any clustering in the table?

Comment: Thank you for your response! Yes, the table is clustered by lat and lon